# How to take gallery image as input stream

Tags: java, android, image

I am trying to read image from gallery and then use that image for input straming , below is my code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mGetImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_getImage);
        mGetImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // SET action AND miniType
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                // REQUEST Uri of image
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
            }
        });
        mImageViewForGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {return;}

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                // SET image
                mImageViewForGallery.setImageURI(uri);
                Drawable drawable = mImageViewForGallery.getDrawable();
                InputStream is;
                is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.img1);
                Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            }
        }
```

In above code `is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.img1);` is reading image from drawable folder name img1 , but now my image is the image I select from gallery , How I can take that image as input stream, as I tried it like

```
InputStream is;
is=uri;
```

But its showing error , well am new to java from c++.

Edit, after @Shawn answer I put this code in `onActivityResult` function after line `Drawable drawable = mImageViewForGallery.getDrawable();` :

```
        InputStream is = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        InputStream Vign = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.p);
        Bitmap bmInImg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Vign);
        mPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
        nPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
        vPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg2.getWidth() * bmInImg2.getHeight()];
```

But its showing me below error on `this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`

Error :

```
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
```

Error come when I use `InputStream Vign = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.p);` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the Uri to the image, you resolve it with content resolver:

```
InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Don't forget to close the stream. (and check for null). context sometime is your activity or "this".

Comment: But when I use the code `InputStream Vign = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.p);` below this line you mention then it shows error otherwise its not showing error , why

Comment: ... you got the input stream already, why you still need the openRawResource? just decode it with bitmapfactory

Comment: yes but I want another image to use it with inputstream , which is in drawable

Comment: by creating a bitmapdrawable from bitmap?

Comment: I update my code , how I am using it in `onActivityResult` function

Comment: following error is on your answer line `Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException`

Comment: I update my question with explanation , after putting your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62296/discussion-between-shawn-and-ahf).